# Update Galaxy Tab's Android by internet

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-tab

Can I update my Galaxy Tab's Android version by internet?
**EDIT:**
When googling, I found some solutions for updating Android on Galaxy Tab, using connection to PC and special programs. But I know, that HTC devices ("Desire", for example) can update its Android by internet connection (Wi-Fi or 3G). The matter is, I can't find such option on my Tab.
Current Android version is 2.2

Comment: You need to be way more specific.  What version of Android do you have now?  Are you trying to download an update?  From your PC or on your phone?  Over WiFi or the cell data network?  Are you trying to update a device remotely?

Comment: @Matthew, see my `edit`, please.

Comment: Great, much better.  I don't have a Tab but lots of Android phones have a way to check for updates in `Settings -> About phone`, have you looked there?  It might not work because that's normally for OTA updates and I'm assuming the carriers aren't pushing out updates for tablets.

Comment: There is no any "Update" option in `About` menu :(

Answer (score 2):

I think that Samsung started using OTA updates on Gingerbread, i.e. since 2.3, so you'd have to update to this either via Kies or Odin before you can update the firmware without a PC. After that, the availability depends on your carrier if the firmware is branded or Samsung if it's a nonbranded version.